# Passing data from a UITableView to a XIB Subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, subview

I'm sure there is a simple solution and I have looked around and cannot find any help. I'm trying to pass data from a UITableview to a subview. I do not want to use a segue as I want the xib file to appear on the same viewcontroller with the required data. The NSLog outputs as expected but doesn't pass to the string in the "nowplayingnib" view.

ViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

SongInfo *song = songsArray[indexPath.row];



NowPlayingNib *nowplayingnib = (NowPlayingNib *)[NowPlayingNib viewFromNib];


[self.view addSubview:nowplayingnib];


nowplayingnib.videoId = song.videoId;

NSLog(@"%@", song.videoId);

}
```

UPDATE

NowPlayingNib.h

```
@interface NowPlayingNib : UIView 

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *videoId;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *title;

+(id)viewFromNib;


@end
```

NowPlaying.m

```
@implementation NowPlayingNib

@synthesize videoId;

-(void)awakeFromNib{


NSLog(@"video id inside nib = %@", self.videoId);

}

+(id)viewFromNib{
ViewController *songinfo = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NowPlayingNib" owner:self options:NULL]lastObject];

return songinfo;


}
```

Comment: Please, share your viewFromNib method code and header code

Comment: ViewController *songinfo = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NowPlayingNib" owner:self options:NULL]lastObject];
- you setted owner to 'self' in + method. should be nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output `NSLog(@"video id inside nib = %@", self.videoId);`
 is in the awakeFromNib-method, but you are only assigning the value to videoId after the nib has been loaded and added to the superview?

Answer (score 0):

what's the type of `nowplayingnib.videoId`  ?

make it `@property (nonatomic,strong)` and check again

rewrite init method like:

```
+(id)viewFromNib{
ViewController *songinfo = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:nil options:NULL]lastObject];

return songinfo;


}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's still returning null though.

Comment: how did your property looks like? and how you wrote viewFromNib?

Comment: Still no luck for some reason. I'm wondering if it's some kind of delegate error...

Comment: how did you check this? you pass it to log or you did not see anything on your screen?

Comment: Ville Rinne was correct, I was running the NSLog inside the AwakefromNib method, and it wasn't assigned by then. Thanks for your help though.